# OpenMP program on different hosts

Tags: multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, openmp, distributed-computing

I want to know if it would be possible to run an OpenMP program on multiple hosts. So far I only heard of programs that can be executed on multiple thread but all within the same physical computer. Is it possible to execute a program on two (or more) clients? I don't want to use MPI.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to run OpenMP programs on a distributed system, but I doubt it is within the reach of every user around. ScaleMP offers vSMP - an expensive commercial hypervisor software that allows one to create a virtual NUMA machine on top of many networked hosts, then run a regular OS (Linux or Windows) inside this VM. It requires a fast network interconnect (e.g. InfiniBand) and dedicated hosts (since it runs as a hypervisor beneath the normal OS). We have an operational vSMP cluster here and it runs unmodified OpenMP applications, but performance is strongly dependent on data hierarchy and access patterns.

NICTA used to develop similar SSI hypervisor named vNUMA, but development also stopped. Besides their solution was IA64-specific (IA64 is Intel Itanium, not to be mistaken with Intel64, which is their current generation of x86 CPUs).

Intel used to develop Cluster OpenMP (ClOMP; not to be mistaken with the similarly named project to bring OpenMP support to Clang), but it was abandoned due to "general lack of interest among customers and fewer cases than expected where it showed a benefit" (from [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/281819)). ClOMP was an Intel extension to OpenMP and it was built into the Intel compiler suite, e.g. you couldn't use it with GCC (this [request](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=27541) to start ClOMP development for GCC went in the limbo). If you have access to old versions of Intel compilers (versions from 9.1 to 11.1), you would have to obtain a (trial) ClOMP license, which might be next to impossible given that the product is dead and old (trial) licenses have already expired. Then again, starting with version 12.0, Intel compilers no longer support ClOMP.

Other research projects exist (just search for "distributed shared memory"), but only vSMP (the ScaleMP solution) seems to be mature enough for production HPC environments (and it's priced accordingly). Seems like most efforts now go into development of co-array languages (Co-Array Fortran, Unified Parallel C, etc.) instead. I would suggest that you have a look at [Berkeley UPC](http://upc.lbl.gov/) or invest some time in learning MPI as it is definitely not going away in the years to come.

Answer (score 2):

Before, there was the **[Cluster OpenMP](http://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/1/6/9/b/e/6330-cluster_omp_userguide.pdf)**.

Cluster OpenMP, was an implementation of OpenMP that could make use of multiple SMP machines without resorting to MPI. This advance had the advantage of eliminating the need to write explicit messaging code, as well as not mixing programming paradigms. The shared memory in Cluster OpenMP was maintained across all machines through a distributed shared-memory subsystem. Cluster OpenMP is based on the relaxed memory consistency of OpenMP, allowing shared variables to be made consistent only when absolutely necessary. [source](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/power/ps4q07-50080141-Intel.pdf)

**Performance Considerations for Cluster OpenMP**

Some memory operations are much **more expensive** than others. To achieve good performance with Cluster OpenMP, the number of accesses to unprotected pages must be as high as possible, relative to the number of accesses to protected pages. This means that once a page is brought up-to-date on a given node, a large number of accesses should be made to it before the next synchronization. In order to accomplish this, a program should have as little synchronization as possible, and re-use the data on a given page as much as possible. This translates to avoiding fine-grained synchronization, such as atomic constructs or locks, and having high data locality [source](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/power/ps4q07-50080141-Intel.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Another option for running OpenMP programs on multiple hosts is the remote offloading plugin in the LLVM OpenMP runtime.

https://openmp.llvm.org/design/Runtimes.html#remote-offloading-plugin

The big issue with running OpenMP programs on distributed memory is data movement. Coincidentally, that is also one of the major issues in programming GPU's. Extending OpenMP to handle GPU programming has given rise to OpenMP directives to describe data transfer. Programming GPU's has also forced programmers to think more carefully about building programs that consider data movement.