# Using OpenMP on a cluster

Tags: c++, openmp

I made my code parallel using openMP libraries. I need to run the code on my college's HPC (16 nodes). When i run the code, the HPC randomly assigns nodes from different blades to my program. I do not know whether the nodes have shared memory, nevertheless the code executes normally. My question:

1. Is the code supposed to give me an error if the memory is distributed and not shared or will it run normally but generate faulty data?
2. Is there a way to know whether the nodes my code is using have shared memory or not?

(I am aware that i can use MPI to use the code on distributed memory but currently i do not have the time for that.)

Answer (score 4):

OpenMP is a parallel programming model that runs on top of shared-memory systems only by the means of threads and cannot communicate with other nodes unless you use special communication calls (such as MPI, or system socket calls, or a PGAS programming model). The fact that your OpenMP application executes fine is normal because you can always create threads within a node.

Regarding your questions:

1) The OpenMP runtime will only see the shared resources within a node, not all the resources outside the node. This means that your OpenMP binary will not spread to other nodes of your HPC cluster (again, unless you use MPI for instance). Regarding the computing resources, the OpenMP runtime will create as many threads as processors unless you explicitly request a different number of threads through OMP_NUM_THREADS environment variable.

2) Your code will always have shared memory among threads, that is normal due to the thread description. From wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)

> Multiple threads can exist within the same process, executing
>   concurrently (one starting before others finish) and share resources
>   such as memory, while different processes do not share these
>   resources.

Comment: Does this mean that theoretically i can run as many threads as i want on a single core?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. That is known as oversubscribing. That is also possible using MPI alone by spawning more MPI processes than the number of processors available in the cluster. That being said, oversubscribing may lead to performance inefficiencies if all threads run simultaneously because there aren't enough computational resources for all threads (or processes in case of MPI applications).

Comment: For the sake of completeness, there are DSM solutions, which allow running unmodified OpenMP applications over multiple cluster nodes: [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13475838/1374437).