# distribute processing to a cluster of heterogeneous compute nodes taking relative performance and cost of communication into account?

Tags: parallel-processing, mapreduce, openmp, hadoop-yarn, hpc

Given a cluster of truly heterogeneous compute nodes how is it possible to 
distribute processing to them while taking into account both their relative performance
and cost of passing messages between them?
(I know optimising this is NP-complete in general)
Which concurrency platforms currently best support this?

You might rephrase/summarise the question as:

**What algorithms make most efficient use of cpu, memory and communications resources for distributed computation in theory and what existing (open source) platforms come closest to realising this?**
Obviously this depends somewhat on workload so understanding the trade-offs is critical.

---

Some Background

I find some on S/O want to understand the background so they can provide a more specific answer, so I've included quite a bit below, but its not necessary to the essence of the question.

A typical scenario I see is:

We have an application which runs on X nodes 
each with Y cores. So we start with a homogeneous cluster.
Every so often the operations team buys one or more new servers. 
The new servers are faster and may have more cores.
They are integrated into the cluster to make things run faster.
Some older servers may be re-purposed but the new cluster now contains machines with different performance characteristics. 
The cluster is no-longer homogeneous but has more compute power overall.
I believe this scenario must be standard in big cloud data-centres as well.
**Its how this kind of change in infrastructure can be best utilised that I'm really interested in.**

In one application I work with the work is divided into a number of relative long tasks. Tasks are allocated to logical processors (we usually have one per core) as they become
available. While there are tasks to perform cores are generally not unoccupied but
for the most part those jobs can be classified as "embarassingly scalable".

This particular application is currently C++ with a roll your own concurrency platform using ssh and nfs for large task.
I'm considering the arguments for various alternative approaches.
Some parties prefer various hadoop mad/reduce options. I'm wondering how they shape up versus more C++/machine oriented approaches such as openMP, Cilk++. I'm more interested in the pros and cons than the answer for that specific case.

The task model itself seems scalable and sensible independent of platform. 
So, I'm assuming a model where you divide work into tasks and a (probably distributed) scheduler tries to decide which processor to which allocate each task. I am open to alternatives.
There could be task queues for each node, possibly each processor and idle processors should allow work stealing (e.g. from processors with long queues).

However, when I look at the various models of high performance and cloud cluster computing I don't see this discussed so much.

Michael Wong classifies parallelism, ignoring hadoop, into two main camps (starting around 14min in).
https://isocpp.org/blog/2016/01/the-landscape-of-parallelism-michael-wong-meetingcpp-2015
HPC and multi-threaded applications in industry

The HPC community seems to favour openMP on a cluster of identical nodes.
This may still be heterogeneous if each node supports CUDA or has FPGA support but each node tends to be identical.
If that's the case do they upgrade their data centres in a big bang or what?
(E.g. supercomputer 1 = 100 nodes of type x.  supercomputer v2.0 is on a different site with
200 nodes of type y).

OpenMP only supports a single physical computer by itself. 
The HPC community gets around this either using MPI (which I consider too low level) or by creating a virtual machine from all the nodes
using a hypervisor like scaleMP or vNUMA (see for example - [OpenMP program on different hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475838/openmp-program-on-different-hosts)).
(**anyone know of a good open source hypervisor for doing this?**)
I believe these are still considered the most powerful computing systems in the world.

I find that surprising as I don't see what prevents the map/reduce people creating an even bigger cluster more easily
that is much less efficient overall but wins on brute force due to the total number of cores utilised?

So which other concurrency platforms support truly heterogeneous nodes with widely varying characteristics and how do they deal with the performance mismatch (and similarly the distribution of data)?

I'm excluding MPI as an option as while powerful it is too low-level. You might as well say use sockets. A framework building on MPI would be acceptable (does X10 work this way?).

From the user's perspective the map/reduce 
approach seems to be add enough nodes that it doesn't matter and not worry about using them at maximum efficiency.
Actually those details are kept under the hood in the implementation
of the schedulers and distributed file systems.
How/where is the cost of computation and message passing taken into account?

Is there any way in openMP (or your favourite concurrency platform)
to make effective use of information that this node is N times as fast as this node and the data transfer rate
to or from this node is on average X Mb/s?

In YARN you have Dominant Resource Fairness:
 http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/12/managing-multiple-resources-in-hadoop-2-with-yarn/
 http://static.usenix.org/event/nsdi11/tech/full_papers/Ghodsi.pdf
This covers memory and cores using Linux Control Groups but it does not yet
cover disk and network I/O resources.

**Are there equivalent or better approaches in other concurrency platforms? How do they compare to DRF?**

Which concurrency platforms handle this best and why?
Are there any popular ones that are likely to be evolutionary dead ends?
OpenMP keeps surprising me by actively thriving. Could something like Cilk++ be made to scale this way?

Apologies in advance for combining several PhD thesis worth questions into one.
I'm basically looking for tips on what to look for for further reading 
and advice on which platforms to investigate further (from the programmer's perspective).
A good summary of some platforms to investigate and/or links to papers or articles would suffice as a useful answer.

Comment: *Apologies in advance for combining several PhD thesis worth questions into one.*  As you hint, your question is far too broad in scope, and good answers would be far too long, to be a good fit here on SO.

Comment: This question is quote broad and I'm not sure if it really is on-topic at Stack Overflow. In any case, why the fixation on OpenMP? The HPC community at large uses MPI and MPI+OpenMP (and possibly MPI+CUDA) because of the huge pre-existing code base and the kind of machines it runs on. Recent development is in direction languages (e.g. [Chapel](http://chapel.cray.com/)) and language extensions (e.g. [XMP](http://www.xcalablemp.org/)) that allow loop distribution and tasking on multicore distributed memory systems (currently they all ultimately translate into MPI+threads)

Comment: I considered serverfault as its more a system issue but from the programmer's perspective I'm interested in things like openMP vs MPI vs map/reduce independent of the hardware layer.
Really I'm coming from a C++ bias where openMP, MPI and Cilk++ are the main contenders (aside from roll your own) vs mostly java centric map/reduce clusters.

Comment: XMP is interesting I wasn't aware of that one.

Comment: As there are two votes to close as off-topic. May I ask to compare with - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166729/which-parallel-programming-apis-do-you-use?rq=1
That question seems to be similiarly broad but more open ended but has not be closed as off-topic.
I've edited the question to emphasis answerable questions over the more open ended ones.

Comment: The question you point at was posted, and answered, in 2008.  SO has changed over the years and many questions which were once acceptable no longer are.  Even after your editing I still think this question is too broad.

Comment: As you said openMP is for one physical computer. And the tendency is to combine openMP + MPI. Distribute work between nodes and parallelize loops with openMP. On heterogeneous HW this would "only" need to compile binary on nodes with different hardware (HW) and have same (close) library versions on them to avoid some possible problems. I think solve this problem generally is complex task either for parallel libraries or algorithms you would write on such HW too. My experience is that is more complicated to parallelize algorithm so it will scale enough, no problem with the libraries i use.

Comment: @HristoIliev I believe Chapel does not translate to MPI (or not only), it can use GASNet and similar (Cray's proprietary) libraries, as can Cray's implementation of coarrays which also does not translate to MPI.

Comment: Indeed the link is to a question from the beginnings of SO, the rules and culture were different then. Would an answer *"What about OpenCL(link)?"* get an upvote today? No, it would be deleted. Just count the number of question-marks in your post, that is a good indication there can't be a single answer.

Comment: @VladimirF, true. I've omitted "something like".